# Can I enable docker swarm when I have an docker running existing containers?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have an existing docker engine running about 15 containers.  It's effectively a production system, so I can't break the current containers.

But as part of a change I am looking at to create a new distributed infrastructure on some of those containers, I need to use 3 VMs, due to resources, its been picked to use the existing docker instance to join the new docker swarm cluster we are setting up, and to run a single container - Effectively a tie breaker node in an Elasticsearch setup.

Problem is that we don't have an environment we can test this on currently, and we need to avoid breaking the existing system for now.

Is it possible to enable swarm on a docker instance already running and will it affect the existing containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to perform a test of this in 3 separate VMs that replicate similar working conditions on Azure and it worked successfully.  It may not be ideal, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953337/612072 but I think it solves the issue I have for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would never do that even if docker supports :). But if you dont have any other stack then we have to do it. 
Have you configure live-restore in your `daemon.json` file? like below?

> {
>     "live-restore": true
>   }

If so, then you can start setting up swarm nodes. Then slowly run another instance of same containers and contain them to nodes. Once this set up is fine route the traffic to your new set up and bring down the old containers manually. The above options makes sure any update or crash or restart of daemon doesnt bring down your running containers.

If you do not have above config, add it and then do `systemctl reload docker`. Keep in mind do not restart the daemon, just reload. Then follow above steps.

These are the options i could think of for you for now. Will get back whether there are any other frameworks supporting this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice  - I had never come across the live-restore option so far!

So we're not going to move the containers running on the old host - for now - but I've setup 3 VMs in Azure and will give this a test using some mock container on the host that's meant to replicate the existing host, and attempt to create a swarm cluster on all 3.

Comment: Good.  This is always a safe approach.  However consider live restore option on your new set up to make sure any upgrades of docker version etc doesn’t affect your container running state

Comment: Hi,

So the live-restore option doesn't work with swarm, so it seems at some point(like updating firewall rules) you need to restart the docker daemon and the existing containers will die.

I can accept that downtime on out change.  But interestingly enough I was able to correctly perform a test where by I had some running containers and was able to join that node into an existing swarm cluster, and start instances across all nodes in the cluster without any issues.

Comment: You don’t have to restart he daemon.  Just reload it.